# Make code run once with multi processors

Tags: c

pseudo code for what I want to accomplish:

```
//gets current running digital singal processor
int dsp_id = get_dsp_id();
if (dsp_id == 0) {
 //code run only once
 //irq start all other dsps including dsp_id 0
} else {
   //code run multiple times
}
```

problem is when i send start irq to all dsps including id 0 i get in the if statetment over and over, i tried to flag it with a global static bool but that did not work.

Comment: It is unclear for me as stated at the moment. Could you elaborate a bit, adding [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I can't add a MCVE as it is classified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a race condition. I imagine that the other threads that you kick off hit the `if` statement before your global variable is set. You need to protect the lock with a mutex. In pseudo code this would be something like

```
if (dsp_id == 0) {
    get mutex lock
    if (!alreadyRun)
    {
        //code run only once
        //irq start all other dsps including dsp_id 0
        set alreadyRun to true
    }
    release mutex lock
} else {
    //code run multiple times
}
```

where `alreadyRun` is your boolean variable. You cannot, by the way, just write `alreadyRun = true` because there is no guarantee that other processors will see the change if the cache of the processor setting it has not been flushed back to main memory. Your threading library will have appropriate functions to do the mutex locking and safely set alreadyRun. For example, C11 defines atomic types and operations in `stdatomic.h` for your flag and mutex functions in `threads.h`

Comment: My first approach was to write the flag into an extern memory, but i found it slow and ugly, this approach was faster and more suitable. Thx!